# How does the JetBrains marketplace know the IDE version?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

If I open a plugin page on the IntelliJ marketplace, e.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1236-identifier-highlighter I see a message like:

> Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (IntelliJ IDEA xxxx)

How does the website knows which version of IntelliJ is running on my system? I am not logged in, the same behaviour occurs in a private mode tab / different tab.

Comment: How are you opening the marketplace website? From within the IDE or by going there directly in your web browser?

Comment: From the browser

Comment: As a side note - the version information is only available to Marketplace while JetBrains software (e.g. IntelliJ, PyCharm, etc) is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in the browser development tools' **Network** tab for that page, you'll see connections being made to `http://localhost:port/api/installPlugin` on a number of ports (e.g. 63342-63344). I presume it's a range so that if one port is in use, it can move to the next.

If you then run `netstat -n -b` you'll see that the port that replied successfully is being listened to by `idea64.exe`, and the response it sends to the web page is a small JSON packet with version information.

So the remotely-loaded Marketplace web page is effectively asking the local copy of IDEA for it's version (using a local HTTP call) and using that information to populate the text of the page!

You can even see this for yourself by trying to open http://localhost:63342/api/installPlugin in a new browser tab (change the port number as needed). For me, IDEA popped up a dialog 'Using REST API / installPlugin API is requested. Do you trust unknown host? / Yes / No' (I presume the Marketplace web page normally adds some headers to suppress this). If I click Yes, then I can see the response JSON version information in the web browser.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The header that prevents IDEA from popping up the warning is Origin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com

Comment: Cool! I guess that it is using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). As a documented scheme that current browsers support, it makes sense it would use that mechanism

Comment: One more question: is this behaviour actually secure? Because I don't like the idea that an Internet page can communicate with a server on my local machine.

Comment: [CORS spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is designed to be secure AFAIK - a malicious page cannot change the Origin or Referer headers, and if you look at https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/built-in-server/src/org/jetbrains/ide/InstallPluginService.kt - it does check the calling page's URL is 'trusted'. Presumably, otherwise you get the popup I saw.